# Does Install4j support code signing using Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure-keyvault, install4j

Our code signing keypair is going to be stored in Azure Key Vault. Will we be able to use `install4j` from EJ Technologies to do application code signing with the key stored in Azure Key Vault?

There is no integration with Azure Key Vault mentioned [here](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/concepts/codeSigning.html).

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 10.x, there is no direct support for Azure Key Vault. However, you can use

https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool

and the "Executable processing" step in the Windows media wizard to sign with Azure Key Vault.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will AzureSignTool launching from Install4j be able to pick up Windows environment variables (e.g. storing client secret) as command line arguments?